# Flask not parsing right arguments in http message

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask server running through gunicorn and nginx that is not parsing ok the arguments of http messages. The main problem is that some characters like '+' are not being read.

For example I get on nginx log:

```
[04/May/2020:11:31:46 +0200] "GET /?action=destroy&interface=web&path=ASIA/prueba_%20+%20prueba.txt&type=file&size=5&at=2020-05-04T05:31:35-04:00 HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

Then on gunicorn log:

```
[04/May/2020:11:31:46 +0200] "GET /?action=destroy&interface=web&path=ASIA/prueba_%20+%20prueba.txt&type=file&size=5&at=2020-05-04T05:31:35-04:00 HTTP/1.0" 200 0
```

But on flask if I try to read the path argument of http message with requests.args.get('path'), what i get is: `ImmutableMultiDict([('action', 'destroy'), ('interface', 'web'), ('path', 'ASIA/prueba_   prueba.txt'), ('type', 'file'), ('size', '5'), ('at', '2020-05-04T05:31:35-04:00')])`

So I get 'prueba_  prueba.txt' instead of 'prueba_ + prueba.txt' in the path variable.

Is there a way to avoid this on flask?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`+` characters need to be escaped in URLs, otherwise they are interpreted as spaces. Try `path=ASIA/prueba_%20%2B%20prueba.txt`.

Comment: In other words, the server is doing the right thing - it's the client which need fixing, as it's not escaping special characters properly in the URL it's using.

Comment: It seems Flask is quoting url before you can actually use it and then parsing not quite well. Other parser didn't work for me (purl, yurl, urllib.parse) so I decide to make my own parser that actually works with this kind of http messages.

Thanks for the tip

Comment: Not quite - Flask (and I assume those other libraries) are parsing the URL **correctly** as per [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-12)'s list of reserved characters. You're perfectly free to write your own parser, of course, but it won't be doing the right thing according to the rules of the Internet.

Comment: I know, but I wish my users will know the rules of internet too. As they keep using special characters, I got to break the rules for a while